# SQL - How to apply conditional range specification in window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am summing values for last 3 months per month and therefore am using a window to achieve this.

```
SELECT
    [month],
    ROUND(
        SUM(
            ISNULL(
                CAST( val AS DECIMAL(10, 2) ),
                0
            )
        ) OVER (
            ORDER BY month
            ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) / 3,
        2
    ) as sum_val
FROM
    myTable
;
```

I have a requirement to use the next or next & previous rows instead of the previous 2, where they do not exist. I am looking for syntax that is something like this.

```
SELECT
    [month],
    ROUND(
        SUM(
            ISNULL(
                CAST( val AS DECIMAL(10, 2) ),
                0
            )
        ) OVER (
            ORDER BY [month]
            ROWS BETWEEN
                CASE
                    WHEN [month] = 1
                    THEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
                    WHEN [month] = 2
                    THEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
                    ELSE 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                END
        ) / 3,
        2
    ) AS sum_val
FROM
    myTable
;
```

I wasn't able to find syntax to express this requirement in the Microsoft SQL documentation.

[Microsoft Over Clause Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments)

I do not want to have a CASE statement on the outside with the calculation more than once, that would be horrible to read and edit if need be.

Sample data:

| month | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |

Expected output:

| month | sum_val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |

Comment: Can you share some simple data and the expected output

Comment: @SelVazi added data.

Comment: You could union dummy rows for months - 1 and 0 so the lookup will be valid. Otherwise just do the case expression outside and conditionally add values using `lead()`

Comment: One way would be to move the case statement into the expression and have 3 SUMS() based on the case statement values.

Comment: @RossBush I really don't want to do that.

Comment: @GettingItDone: why not use `case` and three `sums`s, really? The database would perform just one window function call for each row (depending on the `case` logic), so that should be more efficient than alternatives. And it’s not *that* complicated to write and read.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have a variable window. You have to come up with an alternative outside of the `sum() over ()`. I propose that you either duplicate the necessary rows so that the appropriate copies appear in the right sequence before the first two months; or that you use `lead()` to make the adjustments:

```
SELECT
    "month",
    (
      SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY "month" ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +
      CASE WHEN "month" IN (1, 2) THEN LEAD(val, 1) OVER (ORDER BY "month") else 0 end +
      CASE WHEN "month" IN (1)    THEN LEAD(val, 2) OVER (ORDER BY "month") else 0 end
    ) * 1.0 AS sum_val
FROM T;
```

or

```
with augmented as (
    select "month",     val from T union all
    select "month" - 3, val from T where "month" in (2, 3)
), data as (
    SELECT
        "month",
        SUM(val) OVER (
            ORDER BY "month" ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) * 1.0 as sum_val
    FROM augmented
)
select * from data where "month" > 0;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/egciE7as

Abolfazi's answer is very clean in coalescing the values rather than using `case` logic, but it's worth noting that it does assume that the data cannot contain null values. This approach does not have that restriction.

Comment: I want to sum rows 1,2,3, then 1,2,3 then 1,2,3 then 2,3,4, then 3,4,5 ... onwards. What you are proposing won't give me the intended values.

Comment: @GettingItDone The only discrepancy I see is that in your first query you actually sum over 4 rows while all other references, including your comment, refer to three.

Comment: Looks good! But overall, maybe the  outer`case` expression (with three different window sums) is the best pick, performance-wise - although I understand that the OP specifically stated they want to avoid it. The database would perform just one window function call for each row, vs up to three with your solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything to be gleaned in this comparison of the three options: https://dbfiddle.uk/4m7-fwt_ I think with the same sort order it won't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

According to value of first and two months(Row previous ) is null, it should be checked value lag (Row previous ) , if it is null, its lead value(Row next) should be used

```
select 
           month_
         ,isnull(lag1 ,lead1)+isnull(lag2 ,lead2)+vale as val
from (
        SELECT *
         ,lag(vale,1) over(order by month_) AS lag1
         ,lag(vale,2) over(order by month_) AS lag2
         ,lead(vale,1) over(order by month_) AS lead1
         ,lead(vale,2) over(order by month_) AS lead2
        FROM months
)a
```

```
create table months(month_ int,vale  int)
insert into months values   (1  ,0) ,(2 ,0), (3 ,1), (4 ,1) , (5    ,1) 
, (6    ,1), (7 ,1), (8 ,1), (9 ,1), (10    ,1), (11    ,1) , (12   ,1)
```

Comment: That's pretty clean as well.